# java selenum I can't find the selenium element

Tags: java, selenium

I have problem.
I want click button:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="choose" value="domain" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="mailbox-new_mailboxChooseDomainInput"> <span data-dojo-attach-point="descriptionNode">Domena</span></label>
```

I tried:

```
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Domena")).click();
```

and

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("mailbox-new_mailboxChooseDomainInput")).click();
```

but don't work. Please help :)

Comment: Try to put the id on the label element which wraps the input.

Comment: By.linkText shouldn't work, since you don't have a link in that HTML snippet.  By.id should be retrieving the input element with that id - assuming there is only one.  But why would you be clicking on an <input> element?  (I guess I don't know the frameworks  you are using on that HTM snippet - but maybe neither does Selenium? :-p

Comment: What type of error or exception you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's inside `iframe`, you need switch first.

The `iframe` has the name `http://home.pl/mailboxes`.

Try the below:

```
driver.get("http://lakomika.pl/inne/inne/home.html");
driver.switchTo().frame("http://home.pl/mailboxes");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Domena']")).click();
```

Comment: Is possible to share site?

Comment: is the home.pl domain and I wanted to create a slot machine that creates emails, I can download the page using chrome if you want

Comment: Yes do it, give us more information for try solve your issue.

Comment: i want click "domena"

Comment: @lakomika It's inside `iframe`, I've updated the answer, please try and info again later what did go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[data-dojo-attach-event='ondijitclick:_onClick']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='choose']"));
```

or

```js
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='doamin']"));
```

Also, you can try a CSS selector that will exactly hit that element.